# Is it possible to select an item within a list with a regex?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to create a script which is only selecting an item within a list, with a regex.

In my case, based on a certain condition which should be triggered wheter a specific character set  is present of not within the name, then just select that item.

So far, I have produced the following code within an ansible Role:

```yaml
- name: "Set_initial_regex"
  set_fact:
    name_regex: ".*((-a)+(\\d)?)\\..*\\.company\\..+"
    # This regex should select any FQDN with "-a" followed by an optional number within its name (e.g. fqdn-test-a1.test.company.local)
  
- name: "Debug"
  debug:
    msg: "{{ name | split(',') | regex_search(name_regex) }}"
```

The name variable is provided with `--extra-vars` and could be multiple, but usually there are only two of them. They are separated by a comma - hence the `split`.

The code above works fine with `| first` and `| last` instead of `regex_search`, but I am looking for something more custom.

At the moment, the returned output is (for example):

```json
"msg": [
    "fqdn-test-a1.test.company.local",
    "fqdn-test-b1.test.company.local"
]
```

And the desired output should -in this case- be just

```json
"msg": [
    "fqdn-test-a1.test.company.local"
]
```

Thanks in advance for any help or insights you might provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the way to do this; the following code works fine for this purpose:

```yaml
- name: "Debug"
  debug:
    msg: "{{ name | split(',') | select('search', name_regex) }}"
  vars:
    name_regex: ".*((-a)+(\\d)?)\\..*\\.company\\..+"
```

This returns the desired output mentioned above.

With `select()`, this works fine, as it should create a subset of a list, which is what I needed in this case.

Comment: The `split` filter has been introduced with ansible 2.11+. In the older versions you could use `.split()`.